# Generate/sample random probability mass function (PMF)

Tags: random

It feels it is very easy but I spent the last half an hour trying to find a solution.

What I need to do is to randomly generate/sample the vector `(x,y,z)` that is a probability mass function, i.e., `0 <= x,y,z <= 1` and `x + y + z = 1`. And such a vector should be uniformly distributed among all the vectors satisfying the conditions.

In other words, consider the set `S = { (x,y,z) | 0 <= x,y,z <= 1, x+y+z = 1 }`. I need to uniformly sample from this set.

UPD: one should use Dirichlet distribution with all `alpha[i] = 1`.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @PeterO. the language does not matter for me. Basically, anything will work. (Unless very exotic) I am checking now that Dirichlet distribution. It also seems nobody in the answers there cared much about the vector to be truely uniform over the aforementioned set S.